# How to give 9 features in to svm

Tags: opencv, colors

I am doing a project on vehicle color recognition, which can recognize 13 colors.

Since any color space on its own has some problems (BGR with intensity, HSV with "non-colors" like black/white/silver) so i am stacking up several color-spaces into a feature vector, in the hope, that one space compensates errors of the other. so i am using `{b,g,r, y,cr,cb, h,s,v}` as my features.

I want to give this 9 features in to SVM and train a multi-class SVM.

1. How can i do this?
2. Do i have to do one color at a time?

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN249.jpg)

Comment: Is this average color or all the pixels color? If you learn svm with each color pixel it learn at pixel level which will not be helpful to classify. You need a holistic type learning. If you learn with average pixel value that might not give you proper result. Deep learning based approach or neural network to image classification will fit more in this case.

Comment: the feature vector contains average color values. so will SVM work on it?
i am new to this. :/

Comment: I think it won't. Think of a average of WxH pixels where W->width, H->height of the image. If you use to identify red car, blue car, white car in that case average is ok. If you use to identify car group or types like Ferrari, Mercedes, Fielder, Jaugar etc. which might have mixed or different color in that case average will not benefit you...can you add some picture and your expected result?

Comment: what's the problem in creating the feature vector? What's the problem in creating multiple classes? Is your question how to use svm at all? Did you check the tutorials? You will have a 1x9 Matrix per sample, combining to Nx9 matrix during training and 13 different values in the labels. In this tutorial there are only 2 different feature dimensions (you will have 9) and only 2 different labels (you will have 13). http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html But no idea whether this svm classification has a chance to work :)

Comment: i have added the example image (http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN249.jpg)

Comment: What I'd do... 1) sample a lot of HSV pixels for different vehicles of the same color class, for each of the 13 classes. 2) Plot 3D (Matlab or Python)  these 3D points (HSV coordinates) with a different color for each class. 3) Do you see 13 different clusters? If yes, 3a) find a clustering algorithm that clusters correctly your 13 classes (Kmeans with K=13, DBScan, etc) and then you can classify simply with Nearest Neighbour or 3b) find a classification algorithm that classifies correctly most of your points (SVM, Random Tree, Neural Nets). If no, well, good luck ;D

Comment: thank you mate :) i will try that :)